Is it safe to use a 2.5 amp 250v power supply cord with a USB hub rated for input parameters of AC100-240v 50/60 Hz and 1.8A?
I recently ordered a two-pin 6’ long replacement cord already pre-wired with a UK style plug on the end. I bought this as a replacement cord for a 200W USB 8 port hub. I thought this would be easier to travel with than stacking the US plug into a UK adapter.
The instruction guide that came with the USB hub lists input parameters of AC100-240V 50/60Hz and 1.8A.
This is the cord I bought:

United Kingdom UK 2- Slot Printer Power Cord Cable, Non-Polarized (IEC-320-C7 to CEE 7/16) Works with Notebook Laptop, Printer, Chargers, PS4 Game Console and More for UK Travel (UK)

This is the USB hub I bought:

200W USB C Charger Block,GaN III 8-Ports USB C Charger,QC4.0 Fast Phone Charging Station Hub+PD 65W USB C Laptop Charger Adapter Compatible with MacBook Pro/Air,DELL,iPhone 15/14,iPad,Steam Deck-Black

Is this a no-go? Does this present any risk of frying the USB connectors? Any potential risk for overheating the hub or fire danger?

There should be no problem.

Questions of the unspecific type "Is it safe to" are inviting for open discussion. As this site is a Q&A site which requires answers instead of opinions you should rewrite your question in a way that enforces answers and solutions instead of discussions.

what exactly is your concern?

Thank you to everyone who took the time to reply.  As a first-time poster here with close to zero tech expertise or electrical knowledge, I very much appreciate your input.

Your USB-HUB includes an internal power supply with the specification AC100-240V / 50-60Hz (see text on second picture of your posted ad).
As long as the socket you plug in your newly bought mains cable complies with this data your USB-Hub will neither be underpowered nor dammaged.
Your power cord does not convert the electricity in any way. The term 250V (AC!) expresses that the cable complies with system voltages of up to 250V AC.
Be aware that different mains system voltages may have different tolerances. Western continental Europe allows for +-10% in mains power, target voltage is AC 230V though - but you would need a mechanical adaptor to run your hub over here.
